# Fitnesse is opening Firefox startpage

Tags: firefox, fitnesse

Fitnesse is opening the startpage of Firefox but not the specified URL in the script.

https://www.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/42.0/firstrun/learnmore/

what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details? FitNesse does not out-of-the-box do anything with browsers... I assume you are using Selenium: on which platform, which fixture? Have you tried using firefox manually, did you also get this page, could you navigate to the url described in your script?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

go to this URL and install.
(install a Crome webdriver)

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver